# Interlocked cyclic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, structural-formula, supramolecular-chemistry

Being new to chemistry, there may ought to be some properties I couldn't understand fully. One of them being cyclic compounds.

One particular question about this is, whether these cyclic compounds, say benzene rings 'link' in-between one another like a chain. Having one molecule chain of one benzene molecule, go through the center of another, before closing back up as a ring.

Unfortunately, I couldn't seem to find any term describing it for further research.

This may be a stupid question or have been asked before, but since I couldn't find my answer anywhere, hopefully someone may either point out why wouldn't this exist in any case or redirect me to an answer.

Comment: As a start, check out catenanes: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenane

Comment: Thank you, it appears mechanically interlocked molecular architectures (MIMA) seems to be the term I was looking for.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23547/catenane-optical-activity

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The compounds you are referring to are called [catenanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenane) (see also [rotaxanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotaxane), as they are a close relative).

[image]

([image source](http://www.depts.ttu.edu/chemistry/faculty/mayer/index.php))

> one molecule chain of one benzene molecule, go through the center of
>   another, before closing back up as a ring

While catenanes involving larger rings can be prepared, having one benzene ring threaded through a second benzene ring is not likely.  If you build a model you can see that there would be severe steric interactions, I've tried to depict this in the following drawing.

[image]

---

The carbon-carbon bond length in benzene is 139 pm.  Therefore, the approximate side to side distance in benzene is $\mathrm{2 \cdot 139~ pm \cdot cos(30°)= 241~pm}$.  The van der Waals radius is defined as "half of the internuclear separation of two non-bonded atoms of the same element on their closest possible approach" ([source](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Theoretical_Chemistry/Chemical_Bonding/General_Principles/Covalent_Bond_Distance,_Radius_and_van_der_Waals_Radius)).  The [van der Waals radius for carbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page)#Van_der_Waals_radius) is 170 pm, meaning that the closest approach for two **non-bonded** carbon atoms is around 340 pm.  This value is significantly larger than the 241 pm side-to-side distance we calculated above for benzene.  This means that a carbon atom cannot pass through the interior of a benzene ring, at least not for carbon atoms with energies typically found in an organic laboratory.