# Do molecules with bridges through rings exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, synthesis, molecular-structure, molecules

Do molecules with bridges through rings (in a manner illustrated by this) exist?

[image: example diagram]

I sometimes get results like this when doing Energy Minimization on molview.org. For example:

[image: molview.org Jmol result]

Is this actually a thing?

EDIT: As a slightly more realistic example, consider this:

[image: slightly larger molecule as example]

Comment: When a lactone is synthesized, a small proportion of the chains close their rings when the chain is passing through a ring previously made. There are no bridges between the two rings, and they cannot get separated. But, who knows. May be in a later step, some bridges may be synthesized between the two rings.

Comment: This earlier Q&A entitled, [Interlocked cyclic compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31551/interlocked-cyclic-compounds), may be helpful.

Comment: Bad examples - these are non-existent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_knot

Comment: How about posting that as an answer @Mithoron (sorry for the tone, I don't know how to make this sound more friendly)

Comment: You seem to be asking whether such molecules can exist in general. But are you implicitly asking whether the compound you modeled makes sense? Because what you're seeing is a common artifact of energy minimization that has nothing to do with chemistry. I've seen it referred to as "ring punch" but I can't find much more about it...

Comment: Not unless you rewrote question.  Even your "more realistic example" is not realistic at all.

Comment: @Calimo Do you have a link to where it is referred to as a ring punch?

Comment: Yes, molecules like that can exist (see the answer below). But the *specific* ones you give as examples cannot as 6-membered rings don't have enough space in the middle for anything to pass through. Draw the space filling version of a cyclohexane of benzene ring to see why not.

Comment: @schuelermine My comment doesn't belong to the other answers as it doesn't answer your question, and has nothing to do with any of the given answer. I don't have a pointer on top of my head but you should consider asking this as a separate question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm not sure about the existence of molecules with bridges through rings. However, there are several publications of synthesis of molecules mimicking wheels and axles ([2]rotaxanes; The “[2]” refers to the number of interlocked components) as one shown below (Ref. 1):

[image: Wheel & Axle in OC]
(The diagram is from [Reference 1](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2014/CC/C3CC47842D#!divAbstract))

This specific molecule (**8**; an “impossible” [2]rotaxane) represents a macro-cycle with a straight-chain molecule with bulky end groups going through its center. The inclusion of two bulky end groups prevents the straight-chain molecule leaving the macro-cycle (mechanically interlocked) as depicted in the diagram (See Ref. 2 for the total synthesis of the molecule).

Note that Ref. 1 also cited articles for the synthesis of [2]catenanes, which contain two interlocked rings (instead of one axle and one macrocycle). Keep in mind that there are some advanced catenanes and rotaxanes that exist (*e.g.*, [3]catenanes and [3]rotaxanes).

[image: catenanes]
(The structures are from [Reference 1](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2014/CC/C3CC47842D#!divAbstract))

**References:**

1. Edward A. Neal, Stephen M. Goldup, "Chemical consequences of mechanical bonding in catenanes and rotaxanes: isomerism, modification, catalysis and molecular machines for synthesis,"  *Chem. Commun.* **2014**, *50(40)*, 5128-5142 (https://doi.org/10.1039/C3CC47842D).
2. Jeffrey S. Hannam, Stephen M. Lacy, David A. Leigh, Carlos G. Saiz, Alexandra M. Z. Slawin, Sheila G. Stitchell, "Controlled Submolecular Translational Motion in Synthesis: A Mechanically Interlocking Auxiliary,"  *Angew. Chem., Intl. Fd.* **2004**, *43(25)*, 3260-3264 (https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.200353606).

Comment: The examples look pretty much like the catenane chemistry pushed forward by Sauvage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Sauvage).  The motif of cyclic polyethers / crown ethers, as well as the guiding «pre-orientation»  of a chain into an already existing ring by weak coordination (including transition metal complexation) often occured in Lehn's publications, too.

Comment: Catenanes can also be found in biology: the capsid of the bacteriophage HK97 contains 71 rings that pass through each other to form "protein chainmail". ( https://science.sciencemag.org/content/289/5487/2129.long )

Answer (score 30):

A variation on this theme is [Ice VII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_VII), in which two cubic ice structures are intertwined with hydrogen bonds from each component structure passing through the hydrogen-bonded rings formed by the other component.  Known to occur naturally on Earth as [a high-pressure phase trapped in diamonds](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33570/28871), Ice VII is a stepping-stone to the macromolecular and superionic ices believed to exist in some giant planets.

[image]

[Source](https://prog.world/19-types-of-ice/?amp)

Answer (score 8):

[Ring-opening polymerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring-opening_polymerization), in particular using [olefin metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring-opening_metathesis_polymerisation) which keeps growing closed rings in the absence of linear olefins, will produce macrocycles that are intertwined to form a pseudo cross-linked network, globally insoluble polymer. This can be later "un-crosslinked" by resuming the metathesis reaction with linear olefins.